# How to filter the column when writing the output to a file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

After all processing Im writing my output to a csv;

```
start, end = get_previous_month_start_end()

df.to_csv("output.csv",columns=['Date', 'Company', ...],index=False)
```

Here the `Date` column contains records for few months.
Eg: July/August/September..
I want to write the output of the specific month.(previous month of the current date)

eg: September records only

I know what is the start, end date of the previous month. But when writing the output to a file how can i avoid those rows out of those range.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need  filter values between start and end datetimes:

```
start, end = get_previous_month_start_end()

df1 = df[df['Date'].between(start, end)]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.query("start >= Date <= end")
```

---

If want filter by one month in format `July/August/September`, solution use only `start` datetime and convert it to name of month:

```
df1 = df[df['Date'].eq(start.strftime('%B'))]
```

Or:

```
df1 = df[df['Date'].eq(start.month_name())]
```

Last write output to `file`:

```
df1.to_csv("output.csv",columns=['Date', 'Company', ...],index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit from the format of `start` and `end`.
Anyways, maybe this can help: you can do the selection just before exporting it as csv.

For example:

```
df_month = df[ df['Date'] == 'September']  
df_month.to_csv("output.csv", index = False)
```

Of course, if you want to automatise the process, you will need to replace `'September'` with a variable extracted from your `start` (or `end`) representing the month of interest as a string.